# Multiple array data send via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I have problem:
my jquery code is

```
var sverimas_array = [];
$('table[id=aktEditTable] tbody tr').each(function(){
  var data = [];
  $(this).find('td').each(function(col_key){
    var td_input = $(this).find('div input');
    if ( col_key != 8 ) { data[td_input.attr('name')] = td_input.val() }
  });
  sverimas_array.push(data);
});
console.log(sverimas_array);
$.ajax({
  url     :"_aktas_function.php",
  type    :'POST',
  dataType:'JSON',
  cache   :false,
  data    :{job :'insert',
          PHPSESSID :'<?php echo session_id();?>',
              data  :$("#aktForm_data").val(),
          sverimas  :sverimas_array,
            },
  error   : function(xhr, errorString, exception) { alert ('error');    },
  success : function(data){
              if (data[0].status == "ok"){
                alert(data[0].st);
              }
              else { alert ('error'); }
            }
});
```

In console I see sverimas_array like:

```
[Array[0], Array[0], each: function, eachSlice: function, all: function, any: function, collect: function…]
0: Array[0]
aktForm_bruto: "55"
aktForm_indexas: "1"
aktForm_neto: "47.50"
aktForm_pakuote_skaicius: "5"
aktForm_pakuote_svoris: "9.50"
aktForm_pastaba: ""
aktForm_tara_svoris: "1.5"
aktForm_tara_tipas: "poperine"
length: 0
__proto__: Array[0]
1: Array[0]
aktForm_bruto: "55"
aktForm_indexas: "2"
aktForm_neto: "47.50"
aktForm_pakuote_skaicius: "5"
aktForm_pakuote_svoris: "9.50"
aktForm_pastaba: ""
aktForm_tara_svoris: "1.5"
aktForm_tara_tipas: "poperine"
length: 0
__proto__: Array[0]
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
```

but `$_POST['sverimas']` in  `_aktas_function.php` file give my nothing.

Comment: Can you see in the console what is the request and what exactly is sent in post?

Comment: use inspect element -> network under chrome, use firebug component if under firefox. that way you'll see exactly what it's posted to your server.

Comment: in post is sent: job:insert
PHPSESSID:ns0mb7oj0cf5goa6ia2pspgsg0
data:2013-07-03
but sverimas is not in post